# Acts_as_Inviteable Plugin not sending out invites in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have been trying to create beta invites that each existing user can send out and was hoping to be able to use a plugin called `acts_as_inviteable` http://github.com/brianjlandau/acts_as_inviteable

I was wondering if anyone had direct experience with it.  When I checked the console, it appears to be creating the right queries, but no email or email related errors come up.

I am tempted to just use Ryan Bates' excellent tutorial on beta invites and write it up myself, but I'd love to have something working.  We just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Have you configured ActionMailer? (http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/mailers) Also, what environments are you seeing this in? ActionMailer behaves differently in test, development, and production.

Comment: I believe so.  Here is the mailer based on ActionMailer:
http://github.com/allyforce/RQ-Upload/blob/master/app/models/analyst_invitation_mailer.rb

And in config I added ActionMailer configurations:
http://github.com/allyforce/RQ-Upload/blob/master/config/environment.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of problems you need to fix:

Add this line to one of your config blocks (either in `environment.rb` or each of the files in `config/environment`):

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'somewhere.com'}
```

In `app/models/invitation.rb` on line 3 you have call `attr_accessible :recipient_email` this will prevent you from mass assigning the sender. You should change it to this:

```
attr_accessible :recipient_email, :sender, :sender_id
```

Also `invitations_controller.rb` should look like this:

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_analyst

  def new
    @invitation = Invitation.new
  end

  def create
    @invitation = Invitation.new(params[:invitation])
    @invitation.sender = current_analyst
    if @invitation.save
      flash[:notice] = "Thank you, invitation sent."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

end
```

You really can't send an invitation unless you're logged in (because you need a sender, which in this case is an `current_analyst` not `@current_user`), so the lines having different logic depending on being logged in or not has been removed.

Also, the email will be automatically sent by the Invitation model so calling `Mailer.deliver_invitation(@invitation, signup_url(@invitation.token))` is unnecessary (and actually it would have to be `AnalystInvitationMailer.deliver_invitation(@invitation)`)

You can see a full working patch here: http://gist.github.com/290911

Comment: I've also now put up an example application that may be useful: http://github.com/brianjlandau/acts_as_inviteable_example_app